# OrderBy a date field with linq and return ToList()

Tags: c#, linq

i am gettting a list of records from table, its working fine, but when i use orderby its showing a error if i use this code like this its working fine :

```
var Item = from itm in DB.Items
orderby itm.ExpiryDate ascending
select new Item
{

};
return Item.ToList();
```

above is working fine, but i have a condition so thats why i need to use the following which is giving a error

```
var Item = from itm in DB.Items
select new Item
{
```

};

```
if (Order == "NearExpire")
{
return Item.OrderBy(e=>e.ExpiryDate).ToList();
}
else
{
return Item.ToList();
}
```

Here is Solution

```
var Item = (from itm in DB.Items
select new Item
{

}).ToList();

if (Order == "NearExpire")
{
return Item.OrderBy(e=>e.ExpiryDate).ToList();
}
else
{
return Item.ToList();
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting, ? you can add the condition in where clause of your query. Not really sure what you are asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is Solution for it.

```
var Item = (from itm in DB.Items
select new Item
{

}).ToList();

if (Order == "NearExpire")
{
return Item.OrderBy(e=>e.ExpiryDate).ToList();
}
else
{
return Item.ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. I think you want to add order by only when `order` variables values become "NearExpire" .

try the following.

```
if (Order == "NearExpire")
{ 
    return DB.Item.OrderBy(e=>e.ExpiryDate).ToList(); 
}else
{
   return DB.Item.ToList(); 
}
```

in case you want descending order  you can use the following.

```
return DB.Item.OrderByDescending(e=>e.ExpiryDate).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks Issue is resolved By `select new Item
select{

}).ToList();
return Item.OrderBy(e=>e.ExpiryDate).ToList();`

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear but may be this will give you an idea:
If you have a class like this

```
class Item
{
    private string m_Order;
    private DateTime m_ExpiryDate;

    public string Order
    {
        get { return m_Order; }
        set { m_Order = value; }
    }

    public DateTime ExpiryDate
    {
        get { return m_ExpiryDate; }
        set { m_ExpiryDate = value; }
    }

}
```

and this is your data in a collection

```
        var Items = new List<Item>();
        Items.Add(new Item() { Order = "NearExpire", ExpiryDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(4) });
        Items.Add(new Item() { Order = "FutureExpire", ExpiryDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(15) });
        Items.Add(new Item() { Order = "NearExpire", ExpiryDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3) });
        Items.Add(new Item() { Order = "Expire", ExpiryDate = DateTime.Now });
```

then you can use a query like this:

```
        var Item = (from itm in Items
                    where itm.Order == "NearExpire"
                    orderby itm.ExpiryDate ascending
                    select itm).ToList();
```

Note that the object added 3rd position has a past expiry date than the object added in the 1st position but in the result, they are ordered in ascending.